# tags for specific books/sections

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a bunch of tags for *parashiyos*, books of *Tanach*, books of *shas*, and, occasionally, other books:

> [pinchas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinchas), [breishit-genesis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breishit-genesis), [bava-metzia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-metzia), [talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara), [choshen-mishpat-civil-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choshen-mishpat-civil-law), [yoreh-deah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yoreh-deah), and many others (especially for *parashiyos*)

Some of them are ambiguous:

> [devorim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devorim) (*parasha* or book?), [ezekiel-yechezkel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ezekiel-yechezkel) (book or man?), [chullin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chullin) (book or meat?)

Some potential tags, to be named in line with existing ones, will be ambiguous:

> [shoftim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoftim) (*parasha* or book?)

I think this is a problem (people will not find tags they want, though that's mitigated with the use of synonyms, but, worse, the lack of consistency is ugly, and, worst of all, some tags will be ambiguous (are already)), and my first question is whether others agree it's a problem. If so, my second is how to solve it.

Comment: I see now that [tag:teruma] is being used both for the _parasha_ and for the tithe.

Answer (score 1):

I propose as a solution that we name (section-of-)book-related tags in a way that clarifies that's what they are, tentatively along the following lines.

> [pinchas-parsha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinchas-parsha), [genesis-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genesis-book), [bava-metzia-shas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-metzia-shas), [shoftim-parsha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoftim-parsha), [ezekiel-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ezekiel-book), [chullin-shas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chullin-shas), [chullin-meat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chullin-meat)

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but the examples you mentioned still have some issues: Consistency - 'book' is English and 'parsha' is Hebrew; Ambiguity - Does a question about an idea in the first chapter of the Torah deserve 'genesis-book', 'genesis-parsha', both, or neither?

Comment: @WAF, re "Does a question about an idea in the first chapter of the Torah deserve 'genesis-book', 'genesis-parsha', both, or neither?": See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127. Actually, if we have a tag for each _parasha_ I don't see what use a tag of Genesis is. But it probably will get re-created if deleted, so....

Comment: @WAF, what's a _parasha_ called in English? Both `pinchas-section` and `pinchas-reading` sound funny to me.

Comment: I don't know - portion? Either way, I know what a book is in Hebrew.

Comment: @WAF, wait, wait... I know this one.... Seriously, yes, we can use Hebrew throughout. Otoh, the discrepancy between _book_'s being English and _parasha_'s being Hebrew doesn't seem like a big deal to me. In the end, **if** this solution is decided upon, the details don't matter much to me.

Answer (score 0):

While there are some SE sites that went that way, personally I don't like it for several reasons, but mostly because I think it's unnecessary.

I also think that some of those tags are *too* specific, I don't see real value in tagging according to the parasha. Are those questions really going to need to be seperated from an adjacent parasha?
I think that [torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah) in addition to the book (e.g. [bamidbar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bamidbar) or [dvarim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvarim)) is sufficient for that.

In other situations, it would make sense to go by "book", e.g. for gmara a מסכת could be appropriate.

With regards to e.g. Ezekiel, I'm not sure it needs to be tagged seperately (but I could be wrong here), just include an additional tag for category: e.g. [history](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), [navi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navi), etc...

As for chullin, I have no opinion, since I admit I dont know what kind of meat is chullin...

Comment: I could definitely envision someone wanting to pull up all questions about a particular parsha or book of the Bible.

Comment: AviD, (a) I agree with @IsaacMoses that people may very well want all questions on a parasha (say, during its week). (b) People _have_ been tagging per _parasha_, so will presumably continue to. (I suppose that's not _really_ a reason to keep the tags, though, as each can be made a synonym of its book's tag.) More to the point: (c) You state a solution to the problem I raised w.r.t. _parashiyos_, but you don't clearly address the problem I raised w.r.t. other books: how would you deal with Ezekiel (book vs. man) or _chulin_ (book vs. meat) or even _Shoftim_ (book vs. _parasha_-synonym)?

Comment: I think any time the division is a meaningful division it deserves its own tag. A _maseches_ is certainly a module and a _parsha_ is conventionally one. A _perek_ is not and a genre that appears in a small number of disconnected places in _Tana"ch_ may not be.